# React infinite loop dispatch, from useReducer hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The main logic of the component is that when the page is loaded,  need to save the parameters from the URL (token) and pass them from the `dispatch()` function. To do this, I have a state value were initially null is stored, but after rendering the component  I add a token.

**component.js**

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer()
const [value, setValue] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const query = window.location.search || ''
    const queryString = new URLSearchParams(query || '')
    const token = queryString.get('token')
    setValue(token)
  }, [value])

   useEffect(() => {
    if (value && value !== null) {
      // console.log(1)
      dispatch({
        type: 'TEST_TYPE',
        payload: { data: value },
      })
    }
  }, [value])
```

When I want to call the `dispatch()` function in `useEffect()` the component is reloaded until the memory is full. I tested the second method, called the `dispatch()` function into `useCallback()` to call once if there are new changes. But the `dispatch` function is not called

```
const dis = useCallback(() => dispatch, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const query = window.location.search || ''
    const queryString = new URLSearchParams(query || '')
    const token = queryString.get('token')
    if (token) {
      dis({
         type: 'TEST_TYPE',
         payload: { data: token },
      })
    }
  }, [dis])
```

How can I properly make `dispatch` work once when the component is loaded and without an infinite loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like Rostyslav said, you're not using `useReducer` in the right way. This is different from the `useState` hook: in that one, the parameter that it receives will serve as a default value for the defined variable within the component' state, which is why it's possible to leave it blank. When you're going to modify its contents, you just need to update its value by using the setter function returned by the hook.

However, `useReducer` requires that you explicitly define the way in which the data will change according to certain actions of your choice. It's necessary for this method to receive at least two parameters: the reducer function and an initial state which will be the starting point for upcoming data transformations.

**The aim of the reducer function is to perform changes on the state in response to the dispatched actions.** This method will receive the current state and an action object (which is the value that you're sending via `dispatch`). Depending on the received action, the reducer method must then apply some transformations in the data and return a new object that will override the current state.

The following piece of code illustrates a reducer that would work in your case. By default, the `token` property of the state will be set to `null`. As you can see in the code of the reducer, when an action of type `UPDATE_TOKEN` is triggered, the `token` property of your state will be updated to contain the `token` bundled into the action payload.

```
const initialState = {
  token: null
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_TOKEN":
      return {
        ...state,
        token: action.payload.token
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**Since you'll be storing the `token` into the store by dispatching an action, there's no need for you to use `useState` to save it into a `value` property beforehand.** If you need to access the token from anywhere in your component, you can retrieve it directly from your `appState` variable, as in the code below:

```
const App = () => {
  const [appState, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    const query = window.location.search || "";
    const queryString = new URLSearchParams(query || "");
    const token = queryString.get("token");

    if (token) {
      dispatch({
        type: "UPDATE_TOKEN",
        payload: { token }
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return <div className="value">Token: {appState.token}</div>;
};
```

The full working example can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-lewin-hgelb?file=/src/App.js:0-747).

Even though this should work, you may have to reconsider if you really need `useReducer` or not. **Adding reducers and actions adds complexity to the code, so it only make sense for larger data structures where more logic is required to update them.** In this particular example it doesn't seems worth the effort, as the only action you need to perform is to change the value of the `token` variable: since this variable is merely a string, this can be easily achieved by just using `useState`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in my case the problem turned out to be that I was running the dispatch function in the child component, I checked it in the HOC component and everything worked fine without an infinite loop.

Comment: Now need to think about how it was possible to run the function correctly so as not to write unnecessary code in the HOC, because, according to the logic of the project, many components use HOCs

Answer (score 1):

You said that : `I have a state value where initially null is stored, but after rendering the component I add a token.` if that is the case then you are doing it incorrectly .Instead of:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const query = window.location.search || ''
    const queryString = new URLSearchParams(query || '')
    const token = queryString.get('token')
    setValue(token)
  }, [value])
```

it should be:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const query = window.location.search || ''
    const queryString = new URLSearchParams(query || '')
    const token = queryString.get('token')
    setValue(token)
  }, [])
```

Now as soon as your component renders ,value will get updated.
Now after this the below useEffect will come into picture:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (value && value !== null) {
      // console.log(1)
      dispatch({
        type: 'TEST_TYPE',
        payload: { data: value },
      })
    }
  }, [value])
```

and dispatch will be called.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the `dispatch` function is called non-stop

Comment: which dispatch function ?the one inside component.js?

Comment: but anyways you need to fix your first useEffect

Comment: so now what are you getting ?

Comment: I updated the code as you indicated, the first useEffect without dependency, and the second with value dependency, but dispatch is triggered non-stop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226171/discussion-between-sakshi-and-bavarius).

Answer (score 1):

When using `useReducer` hook you have to specify the reducer function and the initial state.

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  return action.payload;
}

function YourComponent() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { data: null });

...
```

Then you can just utilize your state from `useReducer` instead of storing duplicated data in both state from `useReducer` and state from `useState`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const query = window.location.search || "";
    const queryString = new URLSearchParams(query || "");
    const token = queryString.get("token");

    if (token) {
      dispatch({
        type: "TEST_TYPE",
        payload: { data: token },
      });
    }
  }, []);
```

So to sum up, your code should resemble the following

```
import React, { useReducer, useEffect } from "react";

function reducer(state, action) {
  return action.payload;
}

export default function YourComponent() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { data: null });

  useEffect(() => {
    const query = window.location.search || "";
    const queryString = new URLSearchParams(query || "");
    const token = queryString.get("token");

    if (token) {
      dispatch({
        type: "TEST_TYPE",
        payload: { data: token },
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(state)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, i tried your method and other too, but still problem, dispatch funtion  calle non-stop. Have any methods how can stop function ? i test with useCallback, but same problem

Comment: My code from above works without continuous dispatch calls. If your problem persists it means that the problem is not in the code which you provided. It is somewhere else